# How to solve Cert-Manager letsencrypt issuer problem?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I am using Cert manager with letsencrypt via below yaml code. What am I doing wrong. When I use "kubectl get issuer"  it returns to me : "No resources found in default namespace."

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: ykaratoprak@sphereinc.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        digitalocean:
          tokenSecretRef:
            name: digitalocean-dns
            key: 5XXXX31d821ba586302ff5d38647b701de750823711ff55b2a776c60d8eXXXXX
```

[image]

But I can check certificates I realized that there are some certifications:

[image]

Comment: Did the solution of Lovedeep Sharma works for you? In other hand you are using also deprecated api. It's a good idea to use the current one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are entering incorrect name of resource `kubectl get issuer` but rather you should run `kubectl get ClusterIssuer`.

Try it